# Python overlapping substrings

Tags: python

Ok, so what I want to do is to calculate the power of given password.Each "cddd" gives 20 power, "cdd" 10 and "cd" 5. The thing is they can't overlap.So if we take string "cdddd", it will have 20 power instead of 35.

My solution works but it's soooo ugly, I don't like it at all.It should be more general instead of matching only one specific dict:/

I just sort the dict so It starts with the longest substring, iterate over dict and then cut the substring out from the original password.I was wondering how else could I approach this.

```
import re
import collections
def passwordCalculator(password):

    passwordPower = 0

    initialDict = {"cddd": 20, "cdd": 10,"cd": 5}
    phrases = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(initialDict.items(), key=lambda t: len(t[0]), reverse=True))

    for phrase in phrases.keys():
        count = (len(re.findall(phrase, password)))
        passwordPower += phrases.get(phrase) * count
        password = str.replace(password, phrase, '')

    return passwordPower
```

Comment: You could just find every `c` and count the `d`s after it.

Comment: I'm confused. Why does `cdddd` count as "overlapping", but none of the other ones do?

Comment: It means that the score is 20 and not 20 + 10 + 5. The same reasoning would say that "cdd" scores 10 and not 10 + 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to use recursion:

```
initialDict = {"cddd": 20, "cdd": 10,"cd": 5}
def calc_power(password, score=0):
   if any(i in password for i in initialDict):
       options = filter(lambda x:x in password, initialDict)
       return calc_power(password[:password.index(max(options))]+password[password.index(max(options))+len(max(options)):], score + initialDict[max(options)])
   return score

passwords = ['cdddd', 'cddd', 'cd', 'cdd'] 
final_results = {i:calc_power(i) for i in passwords}
```

Output:

```
{'cdd': 10, 'cddd': 20, 'cdddd': 20, 'cd': 5}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create one regular expression containing all phrases (in descending length order), delimited by the `|`. So your code up to the point where you have the `phrases` list can stay as it is:

```
def passwordCalculator(password):
    initialDict = {"cddd": 20, "cdd": 10,"cd": 5}
    phrases = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(initialDict.items(), key=lambda t: len(t[0]), reverse=True))
    regex = '|'.join(re.escape(phrase) for phrase in phrases)
    return sum(initialDict[match] for match in re.findall(regex, password))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using regex? Does it solve your problem or it must be chained to 
initialDict keys?

```
import re

password = 'ccdddddvvvvvdcd'
p = re.compile(r'cd{1,3}')
result = sum(initialDict.get(x, 0) for x in p.findall(password))
```